# ionic cordova build android failing

Tags: ionic-framework

Running the command `$ ionic cordova build android` results in the following error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/adamgoldberg/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:19498) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
(node:19498) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I assume it wants me to use java JDK 1.8 rather than 1.9 however in my `~/.bash_profile` I have my JAVA_HOME set as

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

and in my ~/.profile I have it set the same way.

My java enviroment however comes up as (`java --version`):

```
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

and `which java` shows: `/usr/bin/java`

It seems my system isn't registering my java path and is still using JDK 9.

How do I fix this bug?

Note: I think the error could be coming from the fact that `$echo JAVA_HOME` returns `blank`. I've looked into bash scripting and the difference between $() and just = but I'm sure I have mine in the correct format.

Note my `ionic info` is:

```
cli packages: (/Users/adamgoldberg/.npm-global/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
    ios-sim           : 6.0.0
    Node              : v8.8.1
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/adamgoldberg/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: which OS? Ubuntu?

Comment: macOS High Sierra

Comment: silly question.. but did you restart your shell?

Comment: Yep. I think I got it to work by running export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v ‘1.8*’`”

Comment: ok.. its just a typo issue... shell wont pick up from bash_profile until its restarted or you do `source ./bash_profile`..

Comment: I have the same issue but your solution doesn't work for me :(
I modified my bash profile to contain: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home -v ‘1.8*’”` but this doesn't work.